# Do we need a canonical borderline admissions question for MA programs?

Tags: discussion

We do have one for PhD programs, but, as far as I know, no canonical question exists about the admission to MA programs with an emphasis on "weak" students. We frequently have [questions like this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/103119/low-gpa-admission-to-graduate-electrical-engineering-schools), asking whether it is worth applying to an MA program with low GPA. It would be useful to direct these to one canonical answer and close as duplicate. At the moment the linked question has three close-votes, but none for being a dupe. (One for "shopping", two for "individual factors", which I don't really agree with.)

Comment: A general canonical question would not be possible because in many countries the admission to an MA program it's straightforward once you have a BSc degree (and the GPA threshold is usually not demanding). Maybe it's better to specialize your proposal just for the US.